# gem install typhoeus - failed to build gem extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation, rvm

I'm receiving an error while trying to install a gem called typhoeus (this is used in following the book "Service Oriented Design with Rails") - I've tried a lot of things to try to get this fixed but I've hit a brick wall and am posting here in the hope someone can help.

Here is the output:

```
$ gem install typhoeus

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing typhoeus:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/my.name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for curl/curl.h in /opt/local/include,/opt/local/include/curl,/Users/my.name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/include/curl,/Users/my.name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/include,/usr/include/curl,/usr/local/include/curl... yes
checking for curl_easy_init() in -lcurl... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I. -I/Users/my.name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10.5.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -g -O2  -fno-common -pipe -fno-common   -g -DXP_UNIX -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline  -c native.c
In file included from /usr/local/include/curl/curl.h:35,
                 from ./native.h:5,
                 from native.c:1:
/usr/local/include/curl/curlrules.h:143: error: size of array ‘__curl_rule_01__’ is negative
make: *** [native.o] Error 1
```

I'm using rvm with ruby-1.8.7-p302 on OS X Snow Leopard with the latest XCode Tools.

From searching around I've tried to do various things, such as try installing the gem under the other ruby versions I have (ree-1.8.7-2010.02, ruby-1.9.2-head, and system ruby), to passing in architecture flags (x86_64 or i386) for the ARCHFLAGS argument, etc.

I'm new to ruby so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'd also like to know how to uninstall a gem in a broken state like the one you described.  `gem uninstall x` doesn't seem to work because the gem isn't fully installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but it seems that your system is not quite as the gem source expects.

Since its using curl and from this [old problem](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2008-09/0051.html), I would guess that your curl needs updating.

Is it the system installed curl, or are you using macports - perhaps its worth doing an update...

Alternatively can you try the install on a recent *nix system - that might work and so confirm its an environment issue.

From the [github page](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus), there are some notes on how to use it with an old curl...

Good luck, Chris

Comment: Thanks for the links, as for curl, I believe I have the latest version, this is from 'curl -V':

curl 7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8l zlib/1.2.3
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap http file https ftps 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Comment: I tried adding the define that the the link (http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2008-09/0051.html) suggested however it didn't make a difference :(

Comment: I added '#define CURL_SIZEOF_LONG 8' without the ifdef surrounding it to the curlrules.h and this allowed typhoeus to be installed. However there is a note in the file about array being negative: 'If you are building an application which tries to use an already built libcurl library and you are getting this kind of errors on this file, it is a clear indication that there is a mismatch between how the library was built and how you are trying to use it for your application. Your already compiled or binary library provider is the only one who can give you the details you need to properly use it.'

Comment: Glad to hear you progressed at least :)

Answer (score 19):

Not sure if this is the same on Mac but I was having the same problem with Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install curl  

sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-dev

sudo gem install typhoeus
```

worked for me but only after installing the libcurl libraries

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You only actually need libcurl3-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev
sudo gem install typhoeus
```

Should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

its libcurl problem, as typhoeus need the header and stuff to compile. and it is having problem.

libcurl-dev OR libcurl3-dev installed?

Comment: I did a 'fink list curl -i' and came up with these: libcurl3, libcurl3-shlibs, libcurl3-ssl, libcurl3-ssl..., libcurl3-uni..., libcurl3-uni..., libcurl4, libcurl4-shlibs, libcurlpp0, libcurlpp0-s...
-- since libcurl-dev and libcurl3-dev aren't there I'm going to assue it's not on my system.